# How to identify which word is the hit in a full text query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

In a very simple select like the following:

```
select * from Table1 where contains(*, 'word1 OR word2 OR wordN OR ...')
```

Is there any way to know which word was found in the full text index ?

I what to make a report which shows how many times a word is present in a certain interval of time.

```
Something like: 
Word     Total
Word1     189
Word2     120
Word3      13
```

I did the following, however, the query is very slow:

```
select p.id, COUNT(ArtId) AS Total from Table n
INNER JOIN @lPs p ON  CHARINDEX( p.sWord, sText) > 0 
where Contains(n.sText, '"word1 " OR " word2 " OR " word3 "') AND dColumn Between 'date1' AND 'date2'
GROUP BY p.id

where @lPs is a table variable with 2 columns: id int, sWord nvarchar
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try using a subquery:

```
select p.id, p.sWord, COUNT(ArtId) AS Total
from (select n.*
      from Table n
      where Contains(n.sText, '"word1 " OR " word2 " OR " word3 "') and
            dColumn Between 'date1' AND 'date2'
     ) n join
     @lPs p
     on s.Text like CONCAT('%' CHARINDEX( p.sWord, n.sText) > 0 
group by p.id, p.sWord;
```

SQL Server might be friendlier to the full-text index with a subquery.